# JAX-RS handle multiple authentication mechanism

Tags: web-services, jax-rs, basic-authentication, restful-authentication

I'm learning JAX-RS using Jersey and deploy on JBoss EAP 6.3. I'm developing a test application that offers Webservices consumed by different clients. I correctly setted up the basic authentication system based on Roles and username/password (Realm correctly configured and UP&Running). Everything works fine when my client application consume the WS.

**web.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>testWS</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>


  <login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>Realm</realm-name>
  </login-config>


  <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>Admin Pages</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/test/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
      <role-name>role-admin</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
  </security-constraint>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.scan.providers</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.scan.resources</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
  </context-param>  

  <servlet>
    <description>Admin test</description>
    <servlet-name>Admin Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>com.test.webservice.utils.AuthPackageClasses</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>


  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Admin Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/test/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>


</web-app>
```

My second step is to consume the same webservices by a web dashboard which require a login form. My idea is to have a free WS to consume the login and return back some token inside the Cookie in the Response; the same token is stored in my Database.
Other WS must be consumed by the web dashboard injecting the Cookie and the server must validate the token stored in the Cookie.

How can I achieve to authenticate the User coming from two different authentication systems?

Should I redesign my whole authentication system and setup a listener:

- if ther's a token in the Cookie -> validate the token
- otherwise validate basic authentication

Is there a way to achieve this by configuring the **web.xml**?

What if I want to implement a third authentication system? My problem is to have the same context-root and validate the caller by different ways.